# How to get the automatically calculated font width from a CFont Object?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using a fixed size font ( eg: "Courier New" ). When I initialize the CFont object by calling CFont::CreateFont function, I want to specify only the font height.

```
CFont Font;
Font.CreateFont( nFontHeight, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false,
    0, ANSI_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
    FIXED_PITCH|FF_MODERN, _T("Courier New") );
```

As per documentation, font width will be calculated automatically. I need that automatically calculated value for some other calculation.

GetLogFont Function is useless as it seems CFont only holds the value we give that is width = 0 and it calculates the value only when it is used for first time. ( Please check the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) )

Another option was to use CDC::GetTextExtent using a single character. But in that case also I could see some minor differences even in the height. For example, when I give -32 as height, GetTextExtent returns 33 for y value.

Is there any way to get the correct calculated width?

Comment: Why would you give it a negative height?

Comment: Check the docs for CreateFont. A font height greater than 0 matches the height with the "cell height" of the font, whereas a height less than 0 matches it to the "character height".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `CDC::GetTextMetrics()`? I've never used it, but it seems to be what you're looking for. You can get the average and maximum character width, which I guess should be the same for Courier New.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you only want to specify the font height, you normally want to use `CreatePointFont`. Second, Windows 95/98/SE/Me are dead and gone -- and with them, essentially all reason to use Microsoft's "text" macros like `_T("whatever")`. If you want wide characters, ask for them directly:

```
CFont font;   
font.CreatePointFont(nFontHeight, L"Courier New");
```

Then, as suggested by @MikMik, you can use `GetTextMetrics` to get the width -- but only *after* you select the font into a DC (`GetTextMetrics` gets the data for a font selected into a DC, not just for the raw font -- especially at small font sizes, some things get adjusted to compensate for the resolution of the output device).

Note, however, that even for a fixed-width font, the width of a string is *not* necessarily `char_width * num_chars`. At least if I recall correctly, even a fixed-width font can still be kerned, which means the spacing is adjusted based on what pairs of characters occur together. The classic example is a pair like `AV`. Because the lines where they're next to each other are typically at the same angle (or at least very close to the same) the spacing will be adjusted to move them closer together -- in fact, the top of the "V" will often overlap with the bottom of the "A". The width of a string of characters can vary even though each individual character has the same width as every other.

Offhand, I'm not sure that Courier New does that, but I'm reasonably certain at least a few fixed-width fonts do.

Comment: If an app works with files more than it does the GUI, it would be a good excuse to create a MBCS app even in this day and age. It amazes me that Microsoft hasn't created a UTF-8 codepage and made it the default. P.S. I'd love to have an example of a fixed-width font that uses kerning! The whole point of fixed-width is to have consistent character spacing, kerning would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: yes, there are perfectly good reasons to work with `char`s rather than wide characters, but most of the reasons for having a single source base that will compile as either are gone, and at least IME, they're not really adequate for the actual data anyway.

Comment: So, If even the fixed width font is not really fixed width, I will need to calculate the CDC::GetTextExtent of the whole line, right?